# how to dynamically invoke web service at runtime to window Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

Window Phone 7 application in XAP file to run dynamically another window Phone 7 Application.

Comment: Your title and question don't match. Invoking (calling?) a web service and starting another app on the phone are not the same thing. Which are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

This feature is called "deep linking", it will be available in the next release of Windows Phone called "Mango" (coming in Autumn 2011). It will both work from within apps and from the home screen.

From [http://www.digitaltrends.com/](http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/microsoft-teases-mango-our-complete-list-of-upcoming-windows-phone-features/)

> The coolest new feature Microsoft showed off today was the ability to create a Live Tile (shortcut) not just to an app, but to a single page or feature within that app. This feature is great. As an example, Belfiore went into the Amazon shopping app for WP7. He doesn’t like having to open up the app and go through menus to get to the barcode scanner, however. So right in the menu was an option to pin that exact app page (the scanner) as a Live Tile on the Windows Phone homescreen.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that MarketplaceDetailTask is the closest API that matches your request.  You cannot nest the execution of one app inside another.Refer this Link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394017%28v=vs.105%29.aspx?lc=1033